# cardano-cli transaction build script (NFT Contract Address Creation)

Tags: cardano-cli

I am trying to send a market.plutus file to test a NFT marketplace to mainnet. I am building the transaction here like this:

```
cardano-cli transaction build 
--alonzo-era --mainnet 
--tx-in $UTxO-VARIABLE 
--tx-out $CONTRACT-ADDR-VARIABLE+5400011 
--tx-out-datum-hash 67882f9c671cb45fc6990a2d14a20b30bfce29ad99a401c283a100662e6600fb 
--metadata-json-file 
--change-address $MY-ADDR-VARIABLE 
--out-file tx.build
```

Notice how the --metadata-json-file field is empty. It doesn't let me build it empty of course but I have no idea what goes here or what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

'--metadata-json-file' wants a path to a JSON file eg `--metadata-json-file metadata.json`

This link shows an example of JSON metadata content, adapt and use as needed -
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/transaction-metadata/how-to-create-a-metadata-transaction-cli/

You can try leaving out this option, or provide the path to a file (that is either empty or that has minimum JSON data).

It's cheaper to experiment on the testnet, but I'm sure that you're aware of that.